# How to register a command to confirm the option when installing programs?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, automation

When installing SageMath through the terminal on Ubuntu 18.04
on command

```
sudo apt-get install sagemath
```

I get a notification:

```
Postfix Configuration
---------------------

Please select the mail server configuration type that best meets your needs.

 No configuration:
  Should be chosen to leave the current configuration unchanged.
 Internet site:
  Mail is sent and received directly using SMTP.
 Internet with smarthost:
  Mail is received directly using SMTP or by running a utility such
  as fetchmail. Outgoing mail is sent using a smarthost.
 Satellite system:
  All mail is sent to another machine, called a 'smarthost', for delivery.
 Local only:
  The only delivered mail is the mail for local users. There is no network.

  1. No configuration 3. Internet with smarthost 5. Local only
  2. Internet Site 4. Satellite system
General type of mail configuration:
```

Each time I install `SageMath`, I have to select the `[1. No configuration]` *option*.

How do I write a command and make sure that when you run the SageMath installation command, the automatic machine is selected and validated
option `[1. No configuration]`? This is something like the `-y` flag convention `[../YES]`

How can I do it? It's just that it's problematic for me to do this manually, since I launch the installation via a Bash script with other installation packages and programs.
Every time I have to stop at the SageMath setting on this option and enter this number `"1"` manually.
In GNU/Linux, is there an automatic validation of an option on a specified command?

Comment: You could consider using `debconf-set-selections` to preseed the selection. See for example [How to use debcondf Show results with debconf-set-selections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381593/how-to-use-debcondf-show-results-with-debconf-set-selections)

Comment: @steeldriver The answers in that question don't tell you how to register a command and its responses. It has "magic strings" like `shared/present-oracle-license-v1-1`, but doesn't tell you how to figure out what to use for any other commands. I didn't find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer !!!
Install by command:

```
yes '' | sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y -o DPkg::options::="--force-confdef" -o DPkg::options::="--force-confold" install sagemath
```